# What was the first sci-fi themed hit song?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre, music

Over the years, there have been many sci-fi themed hit songs, such as [*Mr. Roboto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Roboto) and [*The Final Countdown*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Final_Countdown_(song)). Which was the first?

I would define "hit" as appearing on the Billboard Hot 100, or other countries' equivalents.

Comment: They’re certainly not the first, but I like *[I Told Her On Alderaan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LadgANhOhiI)* and *[Space Tech Banana Clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sybFU8Q875w)*.

Comment: @T.E.D. "We're heading for Venus (Venus)
And still we stand tall
'Cause maybe they've seen us (seen us)
And welcome us all, yeah.
With so many light years to go
And things to be found (to be found)
I'm sure that we'll all miss her so."

Comment: @RogueJedi - You're right. I always ignored that part because it made no sense to me, but its most definitely there. Deleting previous comment.

Comment: I was looking at how we could implement [tag:first-appearance]. More than half of the [tag:history-of] questions would be candidates for [tag:first-appearance], so it might be easier to rename [tag:history-of] to [tag:first-appearance] and then add [tag:history-of] back in on the questions where [tag:first-appearance] doesn't apply. It would still be a lot of retagging though. In other words, I sort of like the idea of [tag:first-appearance], but adding it one-by-one instead of renaming [tag:history-of] might be too much work.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Billy Murray - Come Take a Trip in my Airship (1905)

The Billboard 100 didn't exist at the time of its release, but from the small amount of information I can find online, I understand that this was a popular phonograph recording. Certainly Billy Murray was a very popular artist at that time, but I don't have hard information on whether was one of his greatest hits. It is, however, listed as a hit in [this almanac of early 20th century hits](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=hSCfBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=billy%20murray%20come%20take%20a%20trip%20in%20my%20airship&source=bl&ots=hXl6fgX5h4&sig=wW5Ueu0s3i-t-SdZicm6wBoIMAo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL2tOHvoXLAhVDnqYKHXBGD6YQ6AEIPzAJ#v=onepage&q=billy%20murray%20come%20take%20a%20trip%20in%20my%20airship&f=false). (Google books link).

The song itself pre-dates Murray's recording and is obviously originally written for a female singer. The airship in the title takes a tour around the Solar system and the Milky Way, making it very clearly influenced by the science fiction of the time.

> I love a sailor, the sailor loves me
> And sails every night to my home
> He's not a sailor that sails on the sea
> Or over the wild briny foam
> For he owns an airship and sails upon high
> He's just like a bird on the wing
> And when the shadows of evening draw nigh
> He'll sail to my window and sing
>
> Come take a trip in my airship
> Come take a sail among the stars
> Come have a ride around Venus
> Come have a spin around Mars
> No one to watch while we're kissing
> No one to see while we spoon
> Come take a trip in my airship
> And we'll visit the man in the moon
>
> One night while sailing away from the crowd
> We passed through the Milky-white Way
> Just idly sailing and watching the clouds
> He asked me if I'd name the day
> And right near the Dipper, I gave him my heart
> The sun shines on our honeymoon
> We swore from each other we never would part
> And teach all the babies this tune
>
> Come take a trip in my airship
> Come take a sail among the stars
> Come have a ride around Venus
> Come have a spin around Mars
> No one to watch while we're kissing
> No one to see while we spoon
> Come take a trip in my airship
> And we'll visit the man in the moon

Answer (score 31):

#### TL;DR:  I can think of two early Science Fiction songs - one made the Hot 100 charts;  the other predates the Hot 100 charts, but was recorded by one of the most successful musicians of the early 20th century.  *Purple People Eater* by Sheb Wooley, and *Two Little Men in a Flying Saucer* by Ella Fitzgerald.

---

## [*Purple People Eater*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Purple_People_Eater) by Sheb Wooley

This one definitely meets all your criteria.

> No. 1 in the Billboard pop charts in 1958 from June 9 to July 14, and reached no. 12 overall.

**You're not going to find an earlier sci-fi song that made the Billboard Hot 100 charts, because this song was released [the same year that the Billboard Hot 100 charts began](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Billboard_number-one_singles).**<sup>1</sup>

The song is about a man-eating alien who comes to earth to join a rock band.

> Well I saw the thing comin' out of the sky
>   It had the one long horn, one big eye
>   I commenced to shakin' and I said "ooh-eee"
>   It looks like a purple eater to me
>
> It was a one-eyed, one-horned, flyin' purple people eater
>   (One-eyed, one-horned, flyin' purple people eater)
>   A one-eyed, one-horned, flyin' purple people eater
>   Sure looks strange to me (One eye?)
>
> Well he came down to earth and he lit in a tree
>   I said Mr. Purple People Eater, don't eat me
>   I heard him say in a voice so gruff
>   "I wouldn't eat you cuz you're so tough"
>
> It was a one-eyed, one-horned, flyin' purple people eater
>   One-eyed, one-horned flyin' purple people eater
>   One-eyed, one-horned, flyin' purple people eater
>   Sure looks strange to me (One horn?)
>
> I said Mr. Purple People Eater, what's your line
>   He said "It's eatin' purple people and it sure is fine
>   But that's not the reason that I came to land
>   I wanna get a job in a rock and roll band"
>
> Well bless my soul, rock and roll, flyin' purple people eater
>   Pigeon-toed, undergrowed, flyin' purple people eater
>   (We wear short shorts)
>   Flyin' purple people eater
>   Sure looks strange to me
>
> And then he swung from the tree and he lit on the ground
>   He started to rock, really rockin' around
>   It was a crazy ditty with a swingin' tune
>   Sing "a boop boop aboopa lopa lum bam boom"
>
> Well bless my soul, rock and roll, flyin' purple people eater
>   Pigeon-toed, undergrowed, flyin' purple people eater
>   (I like short shorts)
>   Flyin' little people eater
>   Sure looks strange to me (Purple People?)
>
> And then he went on his way, and then what do ya know
>   I saw him last night on a TV show
>   He was blowing it out, a'really knockin' em dead
>   Playin' rock and roll music through the horn in his head

---

## *Two Little Men in a Flying Saucer* by Ella Fitzgerald

**Released in 1951, this single didn't hit the Billboard Hot 100 charts because the Billboard Hot 100 charts weren't invented until 1958.**  However, Fitzgerald had been one of the most popular musicians in the world for decades by the time she released this song, so it is worth mentioning.

The song is about two aliens who visit earth, decide humans are psychotic morons, and quickly leave.

> Two little men in a flying saucer
>   flew down to Earth one day
>   Looked to left and right of it,
>   couldn’t stand the sight of it
>   and said let’s fly away
>
> They took a look at a Western movie,
>   somebody heard them say
>   If a horse can be a star,
>   think how dumb the people are
>   We’d better fly away
>
> Then they shook their little green antennas,
>   scratched their purple hair
>   Said this planet is an awful menace,
>   let’s go back to where
>   we came from
>
> Two little men in a flying saucer
>   just didn’t care to stay
>   Said it’s too peculiar here,
>   headed for the stratosphere
>   and quickly flew away
>
> Now they took a left in Ebbet's Field in Brooklyn
>   when the Dodgers played a baseball game
>   Heard all the screaming,
>   said we must be dreaming
>   ‘cause this planet is insane
>
> During intermission,
>   heard a politician
>   making speeches as they traveled by
>   But they departed
>   faster than they started
>   ‘cause the holler blew them sky high
>
> Two little men in a flying saucer
>   flew down to Earth one day
>   Listened to a radio,
>   saw a television show
>   and said let’s fly away
>
> They got their fill of commercial jingles
>   and they were heard to say
>   All the people seem to be living in a nursery
>   we’d better fly away
>
> Traveled all around and once they’d seen us
>   said let’s head for space
>   We were better off on Mars and Venus,
>   goodness what a place to live in
>
> Two little men in a flying saucer
>   just didn’t care to stay
>   Crossed a crowded thoroughfare,
>   saw the hats the women wear
>   and quickly flew away
>   And quickly flew away

---

### Honorable mention:

[*Thirteen Women (and Only One Man In Town)*, Bill Haley and His Comets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOSGEEswmqQ) - 1952/1955<sup>2</sup>

[*Mr. Spaceman*, The Byrds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KZMg-fvn-s) - 1966

[*In the Year 2525*, Zager and Evans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izQB2-Kmiic) - 1969

[*A Space Oddity*, David Bowie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYYRH4apXDo) - 1969

[*The Rise and Fall of Ziggy Stardust and the Spiders From Mars* (album), David Bowie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWm03wYBTbM&list=PLuR3CWq59OyrTdWAeVkqH3F6UziQICYeN) - 1972

[*It Came Out of the Sky*, Creedence Clearwater Revival](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuPtOtGF4TY) - 1969

[*2000 Light Years From Home*, The Rolling Stones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcy8o0gj-A0) - 1967

[*Big Yellow Taxi*, Joni Mitchell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94bdMSCdw20) - 1970

[*A Hard Rain's A-Gonna Fall*, Bob Dylan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGJFxpTOE2Y) - 1963

---

<sup>1</sup>*Prior to 1958, Billboard had charts of popular songs (beginning in 1941), but they were limited to the bestselling song of each week;  because songs tended to be bestsellers for many weeks, the charts for a year [might include as few as 3 songs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Billboard_number-one_singles_of_1940).*

*I looked through the bestsellers lists from 1941 to 1957, and there are no songs that clearly fit the sci-fi criteria.  The ones that come closest are as follows:*

[*The Gypsy*, The Ink Spots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yovIyTnUr5I) - 1946

[*(Ghost) Riders in the Sky: A Cowboy Legend*, Vaughn Monroe and his Orchestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ye_zOMU-nTY) - 1949

[*Swinging on a Star*, Perry Como](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CDs067081E) - 1944

[*Mr. Sandman*, The Chordettes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNUgsbKisp8) - 1954

[*Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer*, Gene Autry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ara3-hDH6I) - 1950

<sup>2</sup>*B-Side to the hit* Rock Around the Clock;  *credit to user14111 for the suggestion.  The single* Rock Around the Clock/Thirteen Women *was released in 1952 with the latter track as the A-Side;  it didn't do very well.  When the song* Rock Around the Clock *was used in the 1955 film* Blackboard Jungle, *the single was re-released with* Thirteen Women *as the B-Side, and topped the charts.*

Comment: @user14111 - He specified the Hot 100.  I didn't.  I've edited to clarify that I am talking about the Hot 100, since that's what he asked for.

Comment: I guess you can debate about whether [Phil Harris's 1950 hit "The Thing"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1tKZ3flZZY) is "sci-fi themed" or not, but it deserves at least an Honorable Mention.

Comment: @user14111 - Added.  Thanks.

Comment: [Martian Hop, The Ran-Dells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veSLdNos7q8) - 1963, reached #16 on the BBH100.

Comment: @user14111 - That...  that's terrible.

Comment: "Great Balls of Fire" is sci-fi themed, isn't it?? Also, not such a big hit but inarguably sci-fi themed, [Betty Johnson's "The Little Blue Man"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHsFRsNSi7w). By the way, when it was first released, Rock Around the Clock was the B-side and Thirteen Women was the A-side.

Comment: @user14111 - The original single (with *Rock Around the Clock* as the B-Side) didn't hit the Billboard charts.  The re-release (with that song as the A-Side) did.

Comment: [Alley-Oop, Hollywood Argyles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLD_LTXRmDY) and [Gitarzan, Ray Stevens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v8sDd7DSl8) were hit songs inspired by sci-fi comic strip and literary characters.

Comment: In Heinlein's ". . . All You Zombies" it was the song on the jukebox that annoyed the bartender: [I'm My Own Grandpa, Lonzo & Oscar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3CvRC4fAmk) - 1947.

Comment: Well, I guess that explains why it's so difficult to find any purple people these days...

Answer (score 12):

This may (also) be a controversial answer. It's hard for me to address the popularity of this song in the context of a *country*, such as the United States, because it's not meant for that demographic.

This song is a Latter-day Saint *hymn*, first published in **1842**. Among the LDS, the song is incredibly well know. I'm sure the 6 million+ LDS living in the US alone have all heard the song, or will here this song, many times in their life. That's a population greater than all but the [top 110 or so countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population), and that's without including international LDS members. There are also over 9000 (yes, seriously!) covers of this song on YouTube (and that's after removing the Mormon Tabernacle Choir).

The song is titled *If You Could Hie to Kolob*. While it *is* a religious piece, it has some *very* science-fiction-like elements when pondering the universe:

> 1. If you could hie to Kolob
>      In the twinkling of an eye,
>      And then continue onward
>      With that same speed to fly,
>      Do you think that you could ever,
>      Through all eternity,
>      Find out the generation
>      Where Gods began to be?
> 2. Or see the grand beginning,
>      Where space did not extend?
>      Or view the last creation,
>      Where Gods and matter end?
>      Methinks the Spirit whispers,
>      "No man has found 'pure space,'
>      Nor seen the outside curtains,
>      Where nothing has a place."
> 3. The works of God continue,
>      And worlds and lives abound;
>      Improvement and progression
>      Have one eternal round.
>      There is no end to matter;
>      There is no end to space;
>      There is no end to spirit;
>      There is no end to race.

It has lyrics about being instantly transported to a distant planet named Kolob. Note that Kolob is the inspiration for Ko*bol* in Battlestar Galactica.

Then, the lyrics are about flying through space, throughout eternity, to see the beginning and end of the universe. It also addresses a continuum of space and time.

Disclaimer: I don't mean to offend anyone by suggesting this religious piece, as I'm not calling the religion fiction. Just as Orson Scott Card and Brandon Sanderson have used their Sci-Fi and Fantasy to do so in their novels, I've always found these lyrics to be very Sci-Fi, as a way to ponder the ways and mysteries of the their god.

**I would like to point out that I suggested this in appreciation of a song I've always enjoyed.**

Comment: The problem is that you're describing religious concepts as science fiction, which might offend some people in itself, and might be taken by others as a precedent for treating a religion as science fiction.  A lot of Mormons would be pretty upset if they saw a discussion in chat where people were critiquing the Book of Mormon as a science fiction story.

Comment: @WadCheber No, I'm not. I'm describing the Sci Fi elements within a song. Flying through space isn't a religious concept, and it's found nowhere else in LDS   scripture. None of the (then fellow) Saints I discussed this with back in the day were offended, but there may be some who are. Personally, I take more offense to the label Mormon instead LDS or Saint. I'll take the downvotes, but this has always been a space-faring song to me from the first time I sang it, using speculation to educate on religious principles.

Comment: By the standards I asked for, this doesn't qualify as a "hit" song.

Comment: @RogueJedi There's no "Billboard" for this, so I used the best equivalent I could find - known popularity, YouTube views and covers, what have you.

Comment: The commentary on this post has become an extended religious debate, so I've [moved the comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36008/discussion-on-answer-by-creationedge-what-was-the-first-sci-fi-themed-hit-song) - please continue the discussion there. I left intact the comments that bear most directly on the post; please ping me if you think I've deleted anything I shouldn't, and I can undelete.

Answer (score 6):

Allow me to be a little loose with the definition of "sci-fi" and I'll give you *Santa Claus Is Coming To Town*, first premiering in **1934**.

> It became an instant hit with orders for 100,000 copies of sheet music and more than 30,000 records sold within 24 hours.

While it was a bit too early in pop music history to have accurate numbers on popularity, at least one cover of the song, by The Four Seasons, made it to #23 on the Billboard charts.

This answer, of course, depends on whether or not you consider Santa Claus to by supernatural sci-fi, or supernatural fantasy. But the lyrics "sees you when you're sleeping" and "knows when you're awake" seem like clairvoyant powers, to me!

---

If you like Santa Claus songs, there's also "Up on the Housetop" by Benjamin Hanby, written in **1864**. The song is one of the oldest about Santa Claus. It's been popular and famous since its inception, and some of the covers have been incredibly famous. Kimberly Locke's 2005 version:

> broke a Billboard record when it made the largest leap into the Top 5 in the AC chart's history, moving from 32 to 5 in only a week. It was also the second longest Billboard holiday AC chart topper in the chart's history, sitting at #1 for 4 consecutive weeks.

The notable sci-fi element in this song is the reference to the flying reindeer with "Up on the house top reindeers paused," aside from the modern Santa Claus reference in general.

Answer (score 6):

I like to mention the **1875** french operetta "Le voyage dans la lune" (The journey to the moon, or From earth to moon) by Jacques Offenbach, basing loose at the book by Jules Verne.

The [Boston Public Library](https://www.bpl.org/blogs/post/the-trip-to-the-moon-le-voyage-dans-la-lune/) wrote about it:

> The opera ran for six months in Paris, opening in October of 1875 and closing in April 1876. It opened in Vienna and London in 1876. A review of a London performance describes the music as “thoroughly Offenbachian – that is to say, that it has melody, brightness, and ‘go,’ and that it is not altogether free from commonplace. Dullness, however, is a word unknown in M. Offenbach’s vocabulary; and hence the present production is as pleasing and animating as any of the works we are wont to associate with his name.”

A prince like to travel to the moon. He uses a cannon to fly inside the big bullet to the moon. There he falls in love with a princess.

It is not one hit, but was very popular in its time. There is no ranking possible here, because even radio was not a daily medium in this time.